# How to post nested json by objectMapper and Alamofire?

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json, objectmapper

I am having request json for the post API :

```
{"TokenId": "xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxx", 
"ObjSearch": 
  {

     "UserId":"0",
     "FromDate":"",
     "StateId":"0",
     "DistrictId":"0",
     "ToDate":""
  }
}
```

currently I have created two request models like:

```
class  ChartsReqModel: NSObject, Mappable {
  var TokenId:String?
  var ObjSearch : [ChartObjSearchReqModel]?
}
```

AND

```
class  ChartObjSearchReqModel: NSObject,Mappable {
var FromDate:String?
var ToDate:String?
var StateId:String?
var DistrictId:String?
var UserId:String?
var ProductId:String?
var SalesChannelId:String?
var ReporteesId:String?
var `Type`:String?

func mapping(map: Map) {
    FromDate <- map["FromDate"];
    ToDate <- map["ToDate"];
    StateId <- map["StateId"];
    DistrictId <- map["DistrictId"];
    UserId <- map["UserId"];
    ProductId <- map["ProductId"];
    SalesChannelId <- map["SalesChannelId"];
    ReporteesId <- map["ReporteesId"];
    Type <- map[![\[][1]][1]"Type"];
}
}
```

the Desired response I am getting from my API in postman looks perfect but I think from my code I am unable to send the correct request model and for the my Data shows

> Data =     (
>       );

I am new to Swift and I am not able to find out the problem in the code..
please someone help me to find the solution

Screenshot of POSTMAN:

Comment: Not enough info for us here Tanya, We need to see what request you are trying to make. maybe a postman screenshot? what code do you have to create the request?. try to print the body of the request out and see what you are getting.

Comment: @Scriptable please check my updated question for the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the request structure, below is the simplified way to encode/decode `ChartsReqModel` object,

```
class  ChartsReqModel: NSObject, Mappable {
  var TokenId:String?
  var ObjSearch: ChartObjSearchReqModel?

  required init?(map: Map) {}

  func mapping(map: Map) {
      self.TokenId    <- map["TokenId"]
      self.ObjSearch  <- map["ObjSearch"]
  }
}
```

Now when you have `json` from the response, you can decode `ChartsReqModel` object by passing that json as below,

```
let chartsObject = ChartsReqModel(JSON: jsonFromResponse)
```

And when you want to post the `ChartsReqModel` json, you can encode it as below

```
let paramsJson = chartsObject.toJSON()
```

Comment: how do you suggest to pass values of ChartObjSearchReqModel to ChartsReqModel?

Comment: didn't get the point of passing the values? In the json, you have this as an object i.e, `ObjSearch` so, `ObjectMapper` will map it once you will pass the json.

Comment: @TanyaSinha glad it helped!

Comment: @Kamran Where is this mentioned in the documentation?  So frustrating. +1

Comment: @T.Coutlakis You are right, they didn't put any specific example for this in the documentation. You will only find this in `BaseMappable` class.